# Edit a video to embed a bitmap

Tags: .net, video-editing

I would like to edit a video so that i can embed a small bitmap image at any corner. The bitmap image has to be replaced with another image, for every two video frames.

If somehow it is possible to covert a group of pictures into slideshow video then i want that video to be embedded at the corner of the main video.

The size of the bitmap is about the size of a channel logo and that is exact space it will occupy in the video.

Please guide me in accomplishing. Is there any existing libraries available to do this.

I am working on .Net 4 platform but i do welcome support from other platforms

Comment: I noticed your post in academia.stackexchange. Unfortunately, you won't be able to preserve anonymity because google webcache recorded your real username in several of your previous questions and answers throughout the stack exchange network. I think it is possible to recognize who you are based on your location and name. Next time use a throwaway account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Avisynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page)  with the `Overlay()` function

Comment: I think he's looking for a .Net solution.  He didn't finish his last sentence, though.